# DOMException Error: Is Google Drive still supporting Embed Link with the /preview?

Tags: html, google-drive-shared-drive

If you open a PDF file from Google Drive in a new window and go to the **vertical 3 dots menu**, you still can see the `Embed item...` option being made available to you. As such, I assume that Google still allows the PDF files to be embedded as shown below:

[image: Embed PDF file on Google Drive]

But as a result, I get the following errors being output to the Chrome browser console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'getLayoutMap' on 'Keyboard': getLayoutMap() 
must be called from a top-level browsing context.
```

I even tried with `<embed>` and `<object>` but no luck. I'm OK if it is just a warning and not an error, which is quite severe in the context of SEO. I just want to confirm if this is a bug or Google has officially discontinued the embed service, otherwise what would be the solution to tackle this issue? I just explored the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) but it doesn't seem to offer any solution for a proper HTML embed in particular.

Please advise. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same problem here. Does not even show in ChromeOS.